Can't get working the privacyidea authentication for openven and ssh
I am pretty new to linux and never done anything with PAM so I installed the OpenVPN and PrivacyIdea on separated VMs. OpenVPN works fine until I want to connect to PrivacyIdea for authentication.
I am also trying to implement the same for ssh login. But manly for OpenVPN
In openvpn server.conf I added this line
plugin /usr/lib/openvpn/openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so openvpn
Downloaded the pam from https://github.com/privacyidea/privacyidea-pam/releases/tag/v1.0.0 in /usr/lib64/security
the config /etc/pam.d/openvpn 
Image:/etch/pamd.d/openvpn
I change the url for my privacyidea server and didn't touch other think.
And when the pam is called or how pam works I am not sure I get this
journalctl log for pam
I tried the ldd command and got this results:
ldd resoult
I haven't even try to implementing this in ssh cuz I couldn't even make it happen in openvpn
I tried to compile from source and even didn't got this far cuz there was no curl.
I tried on multiple versions of ubuntu, debian and rockylinux and no luck.
I don't even now where too look for solution anymore

I didn't see any question here, so I'll leave a comment about errors in PAM journal and ldd  output.
Those errors (undefined symbol) means that the linker can not find pam_get_user (and others) function. These functions are located in libpam.so library, on my system this lib located in /lib/libpam.so. Most probably that this library is not installed in your system or the linker can not find it to load undefined functions
Firstly, try to find it using something like find /lib* /usr/lib* -name 'libpam.so'. If this library is already installed on your system, create a soft link of the library to the default search path. You can find these paths in /etc/ld.so.conf or a files included in that file (by default that is the files from /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*conf or/and /usr/lib/ld.so.conf.d/*conf). Once you found the directory where to place your lib - create a soft link using ln -s /full/path/to/current/libpam.so /full/path/found/in/ld.so.conf/libpam.so
If you does not have this library at all (I think this is your situation), try to install it using your package manager. Also check with ldd that you have all needed dependencies for the library. If you have some undefined symbols - look for it's name in google, find the package with this library for your OS and install t via package manager
Another variant is build everything from source, but I didn't recommend this option until you haven't tried variants above
